# SintaxError, Invalid Sintax in for Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, syntax-error

I have a problem with a for loop. I am not able to understand why. The error is referred to the for loop at line 18. Hereafter the code:

```
b1_1_acc=pd.DataFrame([])
acc_cols=['Hour','Minute','Second','mu_second','Horiz_acc','Vert_acc']
### Set your path to the folder containing the .csv files
PATH = 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents\\python\\NASA\\FEMTOBearingDataSet\\Training_set\\Bearing1_1\\acc\\' # Use your path

### Fetch all files in path
fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

### Filter file name list for files ending with .csv
fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]

### Loop over all files
for file in fileNames:

    ### Read .csv file and append to list
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, sep=',', header=None, names=acc_cols, index_col = None)
    b1_1_acc = b1_1_acc.append({
        row for row in range(0,len(df)):
            'Horiz_Line_Integral':np.sum(abs(df['Horiz_acc'][row+1]-df['Horiz_acc'][row])),
        #'Horiz_Mean':df['Horiz_acc'].mean(), 
        #'Horiz_Max':df['Horiz_acc'].max(), 
        #'Horiz_Min':df['Horiz_acc'].min(),
        #'Horiz_RMS':np.sqrt(np.mean(df['Horiz_acc']**2)),
        #'Horiz_kurtosis':kurtosis(df['Horiz_acc']),
        #'Horiz_skewness':skew(df['Horiz_acc']),
        #'Horiz_Entropy':-np.sum((df['Horiz_acc']/sum(df['Horiz_acc']))*np.log2(df['Horiz_acc'])),
        #'Horiz_energy':np.sum(df['Horiz_acc']**2),
        #'Vert_Mean':df['Vert_acc'].mean(), 
        #'Vert_Max':df['Vert_acc'].max(), 
        #'Vert_Min':df['Vert_acc'].min(),
        #'Vert_RMS':np.sqrt(np.mean(df['Vert_acc']**2)),
        #'Vert_kurtosis':kurtosis(df['Vert_acc']),
        #'Vert_skewness':skew(df['Vert_acc']),
        #'Vert_Entropy':-np.sum((df['Vert_acc']/sum(df['Vert_acc']))*np.log2(df['Vert_acc'])),
        #'Vert_energy':np.sum(df['Vert_acc']**2),
        #'Info_Gain':info_gain.info_gain(df['Horiz_acc'],df['Vert_acc'])
        }, ignore_index=True)

b1_1_acc.head()
```

This is the error that python is showing me:

```
File "<ipython-input-28-07d34b6f5c93>", line 18
    row for row in range(0,len(df)):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I change line 18 into this:

```
for row in range(0,len(df)):
            'Horiz_Line_Integral':np.sum(abs(df['Horiz_acc'][row+1]-df['Horiz_acc'][row])),
```

I obtain the following error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-31-0f8d7a8efa8c>", line 18
    for row in range(0,len(df)):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to use normal loop syntax (with a colon `:` at the end of the line) inside a set comprehension. That will not work. Either lose the colon (and move the clause after the colon to the start of the set comprehension), or perform a normal loop, where you build up a list and transform that to a set at the end of the loop.

Comment: `df['Horiz_acc'].diff().abs().sum()` may give you something very similar (or the same) as what you're trying to achieve with your loop. But it's a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve in that loop anyway.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this solves my problem! Thank you! I was not aware of the different syntax for the loop inside a set comprehension.